# How to exclude gradle dependency from specific build flavour on Android

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, fbsdk, android-build-flavors

I have React-Native application and trying to integrate [facebook sdk](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next). My app on android side has different build flavours, let's name one of them **C**, which actually doesn't need any 3rd party dependencies and I need to keep this integration only for all other flavours, let's name them **A** and **B**.

According to official [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/) I need to include this dependency into **build.gradle** file

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'
```

and do some work for **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/><meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
```

in RN to include this native module, I need to create file

```
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

class FacebookModule(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) :
    ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {

    override fun getName() = "FacebookModule"

    @ReactMethod
    fun setAutoLogAppEventsEnabled(isEnabled: Boolean) {
        FacebookSdk.setAutoLogAppEventsEnabled(isEnabled)
    }
}
```

I need to also include this new one to packages list

```
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext
//...

class AppPackages : ReactPackage {
    override fun createNativeModules(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): MutableList<NativeModule> =
        listOf(
            SomeModule(reactContext),
            FacebookModule(reactContext),
        ).toMutableList()
    //...
}
```

which is usually connected in **MainApplication.java**

```
//...
        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
            packages.add(new AppPackages());
          return packages;
        }
//...
```

MainApplication.java and AppPackages files are created inside main folder (which is basically shared for all flavours). But I have own **OtherApplication.java** inside folder for flavour **C** (it has also own main activity, let's name OtherActivity)

If I keep it as is, the flavours **A** and **B** run succesfully, but I got error for flavour **C** that *facebook sdk is not initialised*, which means basically that **gradle** includes this dependency while compiling, but final build has no connection to FacebookModule file and no initialisation happens.

---

So, I want to ask an advice, what are the possible ways to include specified dependency in **build.gradle** for all flavours but excluding flavour **C**?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `no-op` in the dependency on that flavor in which you want to exclude
example:

```
    if (project.env.get("ENV") == "C") {
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk-no-op:latest.release'
    } else {
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'
    }
```